# Is there anything wrong with this sentence? "Firefighters put out fire and save people in accidents"

Tags: sentence-structure

The sentence appears in an English textbook and is meant to generally describe what a firefighter's job involves. However, I find it kind of odd.  Since we're not refering to a specific fire, we don't need to put "the" before fire, but I think it should be "fires" rather than "fire". If you think the sentence is incorrect, which of the following versions can be used to talk about a firefighter's job in general? I would personally go with the first one, but I think number 3 woud probably work to talk about them in general:

1. Firefighters put out fires and save people in accidents.
2. A firefighter puts out fires and saves people in accidents.
3. A firefighter puts out a fire and saves people in an accident.

Comment: The original sentence is correct. Since it is not referring to any specific fire or fires, just "fire" works fine, but **1** and **2** are both also acceptable. **3** is not great because "a fire" can suggest a single or specific fire when the goal is to speak of "fire" in general.

Answer (score 1):

'Fire' can be countable or non-countable, but 'accidents' are always countable. Technically, you could say either 1 or 2, but 1 does sound a little weird for at least two reasons.

As it is speaking about a fireman's workload in terms of individual tasks, it seems a little jarring to use a non-count noun to speak about fire in general, but then count individual accidents in the same statement. It would sound better if they were both countable. But also, thinking logically, using 'fire' as a non-count noun refers to *all* fire, and firemen don't go around putting out all fires, only ones which are out of control or accidental, ie they don't go around ruining barbecues. You can only really express that they put out *specific* fires by using it as a countable noun.

Your 3rd example isn't correct. "A fire" would be a single instance, so it sounds like a fireman just has to do one fire and then his work is done.

Comment: Thanks you. I'm not sure which sentence you are talking about when you say number 1. The original sentence or the one I wrote? I think you recommend "Firefighters put out fires and save people in accidents" I, too, thought "fire" refered to all fir and that's probably why it sounded odd to me. Did I get it all right?

Comment: I agree that _firemen put out **fires**_ (countable).

Comment: @Mohsen You numbered the three options 1,2,3.

Comment: @Astralbee Yes, but you said number 1 (my sentence) sounds wierd, but your explanation seems to agree with number 1, because you say "fire" refers to all kinds of fire. Fire is used in the original sentence. That's why I got confused.